# Change "last opened" date

Tags: macos

Is there a way to change the "Last Opened" date (`kMDItemLastUsedDate`, I think) for a file on OS X?  Ideally this would use a C API call, but Objective-C is fine.  When I look for documentation on how to set metadata attributes, I get information about creating [Spotlight Importers](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Carbon/Conceptual/MDImporters/Concepts/WritingAnImp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001275-208147), which doesn't seem quite right.

This is for a backup program—after restoring from backup, the "last opened" dates should be the same as they were.

To clarify, I do **NOT** want the `atime` from `stat()`.  That is a different value.  You can do an experiment yourself with `touch` and `mdls` if you are not convinced.

Comment: I thought it was going to be related to _DARWIN_FEATURE_64_BIT_INODE as mentioned in the stat(2) man page, but that doesn't seem to work.  Interesting question.

Comment: It looks as if it's read only possibly, and set by the fs.   The mdls(1) lets you look at them, but I think the metadata is read-only by design.

Comment: @RandyHoward: It can't be read-only, since it's modified when you open the file.  I wonder if Launch Services is responsible for updating it.

Comment: I wasn't clear.  By read-only, I meant at the application level.  Obviously something in, or related to the fs code is handling it, but it may not be exposed for apps.  You might have to go the kext route to do this?  Either way, sorry I can't answer it, but I am keen to see how it is resolved.

Comment: @RandyHoward: I'm not convinced that the data is even managed by the kernel.  I might try tapping the syscalls when you open a file, but I suspect that I'd be sorting through an enormous amount of noise.

Answer (score -1):

Use the standard Unix `utimes()` or `futimes()` function. From the man page:

> **DESCRIPTION**
>
> ```
>  The access and modification times of the file named by path or referenced
>  by fildes are changed as specified by the argument times.
> ```

Comment: Wrong.  I want the "last opened" time, which is different from the atime.